# SQLAlchemy session query for mssql OpenJson function

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table "Employee" with json(nvarchar) column "Data". Following query works in SQL-Server.

```
select value from OpenJson(Employee.Data,'$.References')
```

How do I write sqlalchemy equivalent session.query for the above?

```
session.query(func.OPENJSON(Employee.Data,'$.References'))
```

I tried above, the sql-statement I got is, which I didn't expected.

```
select OPENJSON(Employee.Data,'$.References') from Employee
```

Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can use the following form: `session.query(func.JSON_VALUE(Employee.Data,'$.References'))`?

Comment: @rfkortekaas - My Json value is {"References": [1,2,3,4]}
I won't be able to use JSON_VALUE directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for it after lot of trials.
Following is working code,

```
from sqlalchemy import select, column, func

select(column('value')).select_from(func.OPENJSON(Employee.Data,'$.References'))
```